# Angular controller throwing a "script error"

Tags: angularjs

I currently have my app defined as follows:

```
 define(['public/js/angular/RouteResolver'], function() {

    var app = angular.module('marimba', ['ngRoute', 'routeResolverServices']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', 'routeResolverProvider',




        function($routeProvider, routeResolverProvider, $controllerProvider,
            $compileProvider, $filterProvider, $provide, $httpProvider) {

            //Change default views and controllers directory using the following:
            routeResolverProvider.routeConfig.setBaseDirectories('/', '/public/js/angular/controllers/');



            //Define routes - controllers will be loaded dynamically
            var route = routeResolverProvider.route;

            $routeProvider
            //route.resolve() now accepts the convention to use (name of controller & view) as well as the 
            //path where the controller or view lives in the controllers or views folder if it's in a sub folder. 
            //For example, the controllers for customers live in controllers/customers and the views are in views/customers.
            //The controllers for orders live in controllers/orders and the views are in views/orders
            //The second parameter allows for putting related controllers/views into subfolders to better organize large projects
            //Thanks to Ton Yeung for the idea and contribution
                .when('/', route.resolve('Home', 'Home/test'));
        }
    ]);


    return app;



});
```

When I load the below controller I get following error:

> Error: Script error for: app

```
'use strict';


define(['app'], function (app) {



});
```

What am I doing wrong?  I am new to angular and I have set this code up with `require.js`.  I am also using `RouteResolver` in order to dynamically load controllers when routing.  Any ideas as to why this is throwing an error?

Comment: Why do you have all of the unused parameters in your app.config function? What happens if you take them out?

Comment: I was following some code I found but I have removed the parameters now so it looks like function ($routeProvider, routeResolverProvider) but still the same error persists

Comment: Can you post complete error message here.

Comment: angular.js (line 11209)
Error: Script error for: app
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);